# Do you need to type out == null with Element.previousSibling?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I want to check if an element is the first child of it's parent, I can do it like this:

```
if (element.previousSibling == null) {
    ...
}
```

But is it "wrong" to do it like this:

```
if (!element.previousSibling) {
    ...
}
```

? Since it still works since `!!null == false` and `!!anyElement == true`?

Comment: Nope, that's totally fine and I use it all the time.

Comment: It functions, but I would argue for readability the truncated version might not be optimal. It may or may not be clear to the next person following up whether the property you're accessing is an element, a boolean. While it may be trivial to determine, it's still a determination that doesn't need to be made when you use `== null`.

Comment: I would go with `element === element.parentNode.firstChild` for readibility, but I guess that's also fine.

Comment: you might want to use `previousElementSibling` if you don't want to hit a whitepsace node (which is not an element, but can still be sibling of an element)

Comment: @MinusFour: Except that will throw if `element.parentNode` is `null`.